# How to fix the "oauth2.v2.InvalidAcessToken " error in Sonos api

Tags: c#, sonos

I'm try to create a new group using the Sonos control API and c#, I've tried doing other command and they work fine, but I get the "oauth2.v2.InvalidAcessToken " error when I try to create a new group.

here is my code:

```
string content = $"playerIds={ids}"; // and array of player ids to string        
JObject result1 = await Api.SendCommandWithBody(tokenGlobal, "https://api.ws.sonos.com/control/api/v1/households/householdIDHere/groups/createGroup", content, "Post", "application/json");
```

I've tried refreshing my token but that doesn't help, how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reviewing this API documentation if you haven't already: https://developer.sonos.com/build/direct-control/control/

Can you confirm that you are able to successfully use your refresh token to generate a new access token? And when you use that new access token, you are receiving the "oauth2.v2.InvalidAcessToken" error?

The token needs to be provided in a header exactly as it is in the documentation, in the format: "Authorization: Bearer "

If your SendCommandWithBody call isn't providing the access token in that exact format in the request, it won't work.